# did, vs. did so,

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-choice

Examples:

> She knew he wouldn't open the door—but when he **did/did so,** she had
> to be prepared.
>
> She looked at the alley. No matter how long she **did/did so,** he
> wouldn't show up.

Should it be **did** or **did so** in situations like these?

Comment: It can be either. "Did so" is slightly more formal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Did" alone is more casual, but it is also much more common because neither "did" nor "did so" are great options for a formal situation.

In an essay or other formal document I would expect

> She knew he would not open the door, but she still had to be prepared.

or

> Regardless of the time she spent looking at the alley, He was not going to show up.

I prefer speaking, hearing, writing and reading "did" over "did so" every time, and that seems to be the general consensus in AmE here in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

,  , and   can be used to avoid repeating a main verb and its object or complement.

He did- He opened the door.

He did so- He opened the door.

She did- She looked at...

She did so- She looked at...